# Docker: COPY can't find files in local directory where the `docker build` runs

Tags: docker

in a directory with prefix `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/`, there is a example.jar file and a Dockerfile, in the Dockerfile, there are statements as below:

```
COPY example.jar /app
```

I run

```
  docker build -t image_name ./
```

then I get the following error:

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder457658077/example.jar: no such file or directory
```

why can't `COPY` find the example.jar from within the directory with prefix `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/`? how does the strange `/var/lib/docker..` path jumps in?  how to deal with this? thanks!

---

```
    [root@koala 53bdd1747e3590f90fcc84ef4963d4885711e25f]# pwd
    /home/gitlab-runner/builds/pica/eureka/53bdd1747e3590f90fcc84ef4963d4885711e25f
    [root@koala 53bdd1747e3590f90fcc84ef4963d4885711e25f]# ls -al
    total 52068
    drwxrwxr-x 5 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     4096 Dec 11 15:23 .
    drwxrwxr-x 4 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     4096 Dec 11 11:35 ..
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner       17 Dec 11 11:35 APPLICATION_VERSION
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner      644 Dec 11 11:35 docker-compose.yml
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner      568 Dec 11 15:23 Dockerfile
    drwxrwxr-x 8 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     4096 Dec 11 11:35 .git
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner      322 Dec 11 11:35 .gitignore
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     2438 Dec 11 11:35 .gitlab-ci.yml
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner 53271183 Dec 11 11:35 example.jar
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     1043 Dec 11 11:35 pom.xml
    drwxrwxr-x 4 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     4096 Dec 11 11:35 src
    drwxrwxr-x 8 gitlab-runner gitlab-runner     4096 Dec 11 11:35 target
```

Comment: Strange, it should work... Are you sure you don't have any typo ? About the path `/var/lib/docker/tmp/...` that is normal. When you build an image, docker create a context and load everything located in the folder containing your Dockerfile in it for the build. It is stored temporary in the `/var/lib/docker/tmp` directory and is deleted after the build is completed (with or without error)

Comment: @MarcABOUCHACRA but shouldn't docker look for the example.jar in `/home/gitlab-runner/builds/..` directory?

Comment: Basically Docker just copy all the content of your `/home/gitlab.../builds` directory in a temporary folder. So in the end it's the same as both folder have the same content. That's why i'm asking if there is no typo.

Comment: You can find more info about the build context in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/). Especially with this statement :
"The docker build command builds Docker images from a Dockerfile and a “context”. A build’s context is the set of files located in the specified PATH or URL. The build process can refer to any of the files in the context. For example, your build can use a COPY instruction to reference a file in the context."

Comment: This has nothing to do with the docker directory. Your file cannot be found. It is not your build context directory (the ./ in your example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ copying my answer from server fault, didn't realize this question was cross-posted ]

```
COPY example.jar /app
```

This command expects an `example.jar` in the root of your build context. The build context is the last argument to `docker build`, in this case `.`, or the current directory. From the `ls -al` output, you do not file this jar file in the directory and docker is telling you the COPY command cannot find the example.jar in the build context. If it is in one of the other sub directories, you'll need to update the COPY command with that location.

---

To debug issues with the build context, you can build and run the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM busybox
COPY . /build-context
WORKDIR /build-context
CMD find .
```

That will copy the entire build context into an image and list the contents out with a find command when you run the container.